# How do i use the Gaussian function with a Naive Bayes Classifier?

Tags: python, classification, probability, naive-bayes-classifier, gaussian

I would like some help with the maths and to check I have understood the algorithm correctly. So I’ve been learning off of a [video](https://youtu.be/r1in0YNetG8) and I tried my own example. At the end of it I got dodgy results; I think they are “dodgy” because my outputs are not between 0 and 1. If I went with the higher output then yes it has correctly classified my new data but I’m just not sure since the numbers are completely different. I tried by doing the math by hand with a calculator instead of with python but I still got a weird result, so it makes me think that my method is wrong.Here’s what I did, please have a look and tell me what you think:

```
# data 

x = [[65,50],

[62,49],

[130,78],

[124,79],

[54,47],            # the heights/weights of a child

[169,76],              (0), or an adult (1)

[59,58],

[169,79],

[52,52]]



y = [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0]



new = [58, 54]
```

Okay so here’s what I think I should do:

1. Work out the prior probability (in this case 5/9 children, 4/9 adults)
2. Work out the means and variances for each feature and each class:

x̄(C,H) = 58.4        x̄(C,W) = 51.2

x̄(A,H) = 148          x̄(A,W) = 78

σ²(C,H) = 23.44    σ²(C,W) = 14.16

σ²(A,H) = 445.5    σ²(A,W) = 1.5

3. Compute the Gaussians f(x,x̄, σ²):

   f(58, 58.4, 23.44) = 0.08212001659 (child height)

   f(54, 51.2, 14.16) = 0.08038037412 (child weight)

   f(58, 148, 445.5) = 2.129877168 x10(-6) (adult height)

   f(54, 78, 1.5) = 1.343766812 x10(-84) (adult weight)
4. Multiply the Gaussians for the adult and child classes:

0.08212001659 x 0.08038037412 = 6.600837656 x10(-3) (child Gauss)
2.129877168 x10(-6) x 1.343766812 x10(-84) = 2.862058252 x10(-90) (adult Gauss)

5. Calculate the probability using bayes theorem:

(child gauss x child prob)/(child gauss x child prob x adult gauss x adult prob)
(adult gauss x adult prob)/(child gauss x child prob x adult gauss x adult prob)

(6.600837656 x10(-3) x 5/9)/(6.600837656 x10(-3) x 5/9 x 2.862058252 x10(-90) x 4/9) = 9.841633571 x10(89)
(2.862058252 x10(-90) x 4/9)/(6.600837656 x10(-3) x 5/9 x 2.862058252 x10(-90) x 4/9) = 341.3788376

...so those were the final probabilities. If i went with the higher one which you are supposed to then the algorithm would've correctly classed the data as a child, but the probabilities were not between 0 and 1 which makes me think this method may not work for other data. I also ran the data through Scikit learn which classified the new data as a child also. Please let me know what you think and if i have been unclear about something, let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You got the [Bayes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) wrong. There should be a plus in the denominator:

(child gauss x child prob)/(child gauss x child prob + adult gauss x adult prob)

(adult gauss x adult prob)/(child gauss x child prob + adult gauss x adult prob)